# Can you skip cinematics in return to castle chordead?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

These cinematics repeat over and over again, especially if you respawn often (bossfight for example), so is there a way to skip them or turn them off? Keys like <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>WHITESPACE</kbd> won't work and <kbd>ESC</kbd> is already mapped to open the menu...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly, there does not appear to be any way to skip cinematics, in house of the chordead.

This is probably the most played minigame for Rocksmith,between me and my friends. Being as frustrated, we reverted to the "try everything" approach.

No key on the keyboard forces a cutscene to skip. As you state, <kbd>ESC</kbd> opens the menu. I thought there might be an option, somewhere, to skip individual or all cutscenes. After exploring, unfortunetly not.